# Read a files in a directory and send files one by one to another shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a Landing zone directory, from there I would like to get files as an input to another shell script. I do not have any idea about the file name which was stored in Landing Zone.

Can anyone share the shell script how to get files from Landing zone and process the file as an input to another shell script?

Thanks in Advance,
Robin David

Answer (score 0):

You could something like

```
#switch to your landingzone directory
cd /tmp/landingzone
for FILE in *;do 
     echo "processing $FILE"
     #do wahtever you need to do with the file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
    echo "got ==$entry=="
    # do anything with the file (or directory) in the LandingZone
    # e.g.
    /path/to/my_other_script "$entry"
    #or
    /path/to/my_another_script < "$entry"
done < <(find /some/path/to/LandingZone -print0)
```

of course, you can add some more args to `find` like: `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f` etc...